# Angular mat-Table and using *ngIf directive within a column

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-table and within a couple of columns I want to have different behavior depending upon data.  I have determined how to do it within one column, but if I apply the same technique to two/multiple columns I experience the behavior in attached screenshot.  What is the best way to accomplish this and what am I doing wrong.

That attached screenshot shows that the column "Amount" displays but the data is displayed in the same column as Payment Type.

I'm using Angular 12.

```
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  class="invoice-header-cell">Payment Type</th>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let invoice; let i = dataIndex" class="invoice-cell" style="width:200px !important;margin-top:10px;">
            <td  *ngIf="invoice.paymentType !== ''" style="vertical-align: middle;"  class="invoice-cell"> {{invoice.paymentType}} </td>
            <td  *ngIf="invoice.paymentType ===''" style="vertical-align: middle;width:200px;"  class="invoice-cell"> 
              <select>
                <option value="NO_SELECTION">--Choose--</option>
                <option value="CASH">CASH</option>
                <option value="CHECK">CHECK</option>
                <option value="AMEX">AMEX</option>
                <option value="DISCOVER">DISCOVER</option>
                <option value="VISA MC">VISA MC</option>
              </select>
            </td>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

 <ng-container matColumnDef="paymentAmount">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  class="invoice-header-cell">Amount</th>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let invoice; let i = dataIndex" class="invoice-cell" style="width:200px !important;" >
            <td  *ngIf="invoice.paymentAmount !== 0"   class="invoice-cell" style="width:100px;"> {{invoice.paymentAmount}} </td>
            <td  *ngIf="invoice.paymentAmount === 0"   class="invoice-cell"> 
             zero balance
            </td>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
```

[image]

Comment: I want to be able to have conditional evaluation of data and to display different data/elements, like in the top matColumnDef above.  And not to have the output mangled.  If I use two columns in a row with the HTML/syntax above I get the mangled output.

Comment: Can you show what type of correction do you want in image you shared for the output ? What's wrong in image and how would you like to see it ?

Comment: Give me sample data source

Comment: I feel thet the problem is the "styles" in cell. you want differents width based in the value of paymentAmmount and paymentType. Really do you want it?

Comment: @Streamers Can You please give sample data ?